# Issue: Material UI Dialog control is hiding window scroll

Tags: material-design, material-ui

> In any page if window scroll is visible, If we open the material-ui
>   dialog control it hides the scroll because of this page is shaking to
>   adjust the width and height.Again on the close of dialog that scroll
>   come because of this again, page shakes. **How can we prevent the dialog
>   control to hide the scroll?**

```
<Dialog
  autoScrollBodyContent
  title={<div> {props.title} </div>}
  actions={onGetActionsByType(props)}
  modal={false}
  open={props.open}
  style={dialogContainer}
  titleStyle={props.titleStyle}
  contentStyle={customContentStyle}
  actionsContainerStyle={dialogActionsStyle}
 >  
</Dialog>
```

This is the code to open the dialog.

Comment: Do you have the code to reproduce this issue? If so, please include it. Otherwise, it's hard to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @AndrewT. It's reproducible, Just open a dialog if there is any window scroll in your page.After opening dialog, it will collapse the scroll and after closing the dialog that scroll will come.

Comment: @AndrewT didn't meant that. You have to add code if any, required to reproduce. Add a snippet if any, needed to reprod this issue. Also add a reference, from where you copied the Quoted text jack123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I found the answer by googling it a lot:- 
We can get the solution here 
[PreventDisapearofWindowScroll](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/897)

We have to set:-

```
 document.body.style.overflow = 'auto',
```

Any one can find the detail from above link.